# Compare a pandas moving window to a list to find the window with least error

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, rolling-computation

I have reduced my data set to the last few steps. My pandas dataframe looks like this

```
    FAC
0   1
1   2
2   1
3   3
4   2
5   1
6   2
7   1
8   1
9   3
10  2
11  1
12  2
13  3
14  1
```

I also have a list that I have identified to match.

```
match_list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
```

what I am looking for is the slide through (5 item window) the data frame column and spot the row that matched the list pattern. The final result is something that looks like this. I will be thankful for any help.

```
    FAC Error
0   1   some val
1   2   some val
2   1   some val
3   3   some val
4   2   some val
5   1   some val
6   2   some val
7   1   0
8   1   some val
9   3   some val
10  2   some val
11  1   some val
12  2   some val
13  3   some val
14  1   some val
```

Comment: What happens when the dataframe matches the pattern of `match_list`? What needs to be done then?

Comment: for example if the process started with row 3, the sequence 1,2,1 matches but the last two does not, so the the row 3 should be populated with error = 2/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `rolling`:

```
match_list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
match_list = np.array(match_list)

def match(x):
    return (len(x)==len(match_list) and (x==match_list).all())


df['error'] = np.where(df.FAC.rolling(5, center=True).apply(match)==1, 0, 'some value')
```

Output:

```
    FAC       error
0     1  some value
1     2  some value
2     1  some value
3     3  some value
4     2  some value
5     1  some value
6     2  some value
7     1           0
8     1  some value
9     3  some value
10    2  some value
11    1  some value
12    2  some value
13    3  some value
14    1  some value
```

---

**Update**: to count the match, you can simply do `mean` instead of `all` inside the function:

```
def count_match(x):
    return (len(x)==len(match_list))* (x==match_list).mean()

df['error'] = df.FAC.rolling(5,center=True).apply(count_match)
```

Output:

```
    FAC  error
0     1    NaN
1     2    NaN
2     1    0.6
3     3    0.0
4     2    0.4
5     1    0.4
6     2    0.2
7     1    1.0
8     1    0.2
9     3    0.2
10    2    0.4
11    1    0.6
12    2    0.0
13    3    NaN
14    1    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me compute the error based on the match. for example if the process starte with row 3, the sequence 1,2,1 matches but the last two does not, so the the row 3 should be populated with error = 2/5

Comment: @DarkKnight see udpate.

Comment: you are awesome!